# What am I doing wrong downloading data from parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to download some data from parse but I get an error message saying "Value of type 'PFObject' has no member 'name' What am I doing wrong?

here is my parse dashboard screenshot

[image]

here is my code to upload the data to parse:

```
var coordinates = PFGeoPoint (latitude: (newCoordinate2.latitude), longitude:(newCoordinate2.longitude))

var aboutSpot = PFObject(className: "spotdetail")

aboutSpot ["PFGeoPoint"] = coordinates
aboutSpot["name"] = "name"
aboutSpot.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
    print("separate name and geopoint have been saved")
}
```

and here is my code to download my data:

```
var query = PFObject.query()
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) in

    if let places1 = objects {

        for object in places1 {

            if let spotdetail = object as? PFObject {

                self.rideSpots.append(spotdetail.name!)

            }
        }

    }

    print(self.rideSpots)

})
```

also not that on the line that says

```
 if let spotdetail = object as? PFObject {
```

I get a warning saying `"conditional cast from 'PFObject' to 'PFObject' always succeeds`

I can probably solve this pretty easily but I wanted to mention it in case it could help solve the issue

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a property called `name`. That's probably the reason why you are using it as `["name"]` in the upload code.

Comment: Try `spotdetail["name"]` instead of `spot detail.name!`?

Comment: it seems that you get all objects, not only `sportdetails`. You have to specify the class name of your query to get object from `sportdetails`only.

Comment: @ConnorNeville I just tried you suggestion but it tells me " 'AnyObject' is nor convertible to 'String' did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast? and suggest that I insert "as! (String) but if I do , it keeps suggesting the same over and over

Comment: @HoaParis How should I do this ? I thought that what I was doing with `if let spotdetail = object as? PFObject {
                        
                        self.rideSpots.append(spotdetail["name"])
                        
                    }`

Comment: No, it's not correct. it just check if it can convert your object to a PFObject or not. Use this: `var query  = PFQuery(className: "sportdetail")`  -> it searchs in your table `sportdetail`only.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with probably helped me from getting future errors @HoaParis However I still have the same error for now